# optimization: minimize using memory

Tags: memory, mobile, optimization, numbers

I need to load 9digit mobile number on memory for checking used number.
How can I optimize memory space?
I want to load all of data on the memory.

Let me know how to do or keywords. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need multiple structures. Each 9 digit mobile number requires slightly less than 30 bits of memory. When the number of those number is small, simply a (sorted) array, or a *dynamic hash table* of 32-bit integers should be adequate.

When the amount of those numbers increases, a bit vector of size 10^9 bits or ~119 MB associating one bit for each possible number outperforms the hash table.

The break even point may be somewhere around 28 million numbers (or 90% of 119 MB).

One method to consider for a small amount of numbers would be a radix tree (patricia trie), which is searchable.